# Connecting to SQL server database with JavaFX

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, javafx

I am not getting the idea to connect with SQL Server. I want to know the connection and then the fetching the data from SQL Server.

Please suggest some idea about this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/GettingStartedTOC.fm.html

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javafx-database-programming-with-java-db/224202518